# Data is being sent to database as null after sending from frontend

Tags: spring, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to make a connection between an `Event` and `User` entity, so that I can save entrants into an event. I have never used `@ManyToMany` mapping before and so have been following a tutorial. When I try to post the data via postman (`eventid` and `userid`), I get null values for both.

So far I have, User and Event entity,

```
@Data
//Entity maps object to database
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "member")
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {

//More fields

//Relationship between user and events to get entrants
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userid", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Entrants> entrants;
```

```
@Data
//Entity maps object to database
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event implements Serializable {

//More fields

//Relationship with event and users for entrants to an event
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "eventid",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Entrants> entrants;
```

Then I have an Entrant Entity to hold the entrants to an event.

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Entrants implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User userid;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    Event eventid;


}
```

Then in my controller,

```
@PostMapping("/management/events/entrants")
    GenericResponse createEntrant(@Valid @RequestBody Entrants entrant) {
        System.out.println("entrant is: " +entrant);
        entrantService.save(entrant);
        return new GenericResponse("Entrant saved");
    }
```

EntrantService

```
public Entrants save(Entrants entrants) {
        return entrantRepository.save(entrants);
    }
```

and the repository is the standard and the above utilises the save() method.

If I post the following in Postman,

```
{
    "user_id": 1,
    "event_id": 1
}
```

I get this
`entrant is: Entrants(id=null, userid=null, eventid=null)`
`id` is obviously created by Spring, but the `userid` and `eventid` are null.

From my limited knowledge I think this is something to do with the 2 fields in the `Entrants` entity, being of type `User` and `Event` rather than `int`. But I am not sure how to get around this.

The tutorial I followed wasnt really based on my implementation so I have had to change quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Dto in your controller like this:

```java
@PostMapping("/management/events/entrants")
   createEntrant(@Valid @RequestBody EntrantDto entrant) {
        System.out.println("entrant is: " +entrant);
        entrantService.save(entrant);
        return new GenericResponse("Entrant saved");
    }
```

`EntrantDto.java`

```java
public class EntrantDto {
    private Long user_id;
    private Long event_id;
    // no-args constructor, getter, setter,...
}
```

and modify a little bit your service like

```
public Entrants save(EntrantDto entrant) {
    User user = this.userRepository.findById(entrant.getUser_id()).orElseThrown(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    Event event = this.eventRepository.findById(entrant.getEvent_id()).orElseThrown(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    Entrants entrants = new Entrants(user, event);
    return entrantRepository.save(entrants);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but I am getting a stack overflow error when I try to create the Event using `this.eventRepository.findById(entrant.getEvent_id()).orElseThrown(IllegalArgumentException::new);`

Comment: Yes, absolutely, because your `@Data` includes the `HashCode` method.  So, you should use 3 `@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor` annotations instead of only 1 `@Data` annotation.

Comment: Thanks, I did find a way around this by instead adding the @ToString.Exclude annotation to the Course and Event in the Event Entity. This has worked. Although I am still not getting the userid and eventid passed to the database. But I havent had chance to look into that yet

Comment: I think the problem is, it is saving an `Entrant`  which holds all the details of the user and the event. Where I just want to save the `userid` and `eventid`

Comment: it hasn't been saved? After you'd saved it, what did you receive? An entrant row with (id=x, user_id=null, event_id=null) ?

Comment: `it is saving an Entrant which holds all the details of the user and the event`, It doesn't matter, it's the way it works, the persistent context will take care of it for you, as long as you create `Entrants` contains `User` and `Event` in it, it will be saved into database as user_id and event_id.

Comment: Yes I get id= X userid=null eventid= null

Comment: Also in database, the column userid and eventid are saved as bigint data type? Does this sound right? I'm still new to JPA, so not sure what data type it would create columns with when the column is of type Object

Comment: Yes, it's ok Long-BigInt, BigSerial. You could add these lines `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` in your application.properties file. And run your save method again, so you can see sql statements and make sure it calls some `insert` statements.

Comment: I already use those in my application.yaml file and they're called. And it runs insert. But it still doesn't save a value. I've even checked that the values passed from postman are there when they arrive in spring controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238921/discussion-between-james-smith-and-linh-vu).